# wp_insert_post -> post_content not showing

Tags: wp-insert-post, post-content

I have a problem with wp_insert_post.

When I'm attempting to insert my post, the post_content essentially shows up as just blanks spaces. I even went into MySQL to confirm. Everything else, post_title, post_excerpt, etc shows up just fine.

I did a print_r($this->postData) Just prior to passing this to wp_insert_post just to be sure it wasn't empty and the right data was present.

The contents of the data are

```
<object> ... </object>
```

Would that be an issue?

Here's my code that creates the $this->postData variable that's passed into wp_insert_post.

```
$this->postData = array(
        'post_content' => $this->jsonData['data'],
        'post_title' => $this->jsonData['title'],
        'post_excerpt' => $this->jsonData['description'],
        'tags_input' => $this->jsonData['tags'],
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: is `$this->jsonData['data']` unset or empty?

Comment: Nope it isn't. I did a print_r($this->jsonData['data']) Just prior to passing this to wp_insert_post just to be sure it wasn't empty and the right data was present.

Comment: I mean print_r($this->postData)

Answer (score 3):

OK, SO this is what I found out, the data

```
<object>...</object>
```

was the culprit. Wordpress sanitizes the input before committing to the database. Other non allowed tags include

```
<embed>...</embed>
```

I've seen this solution online

```
$postData = array( 
    ...
    'filter'=>true
    ...
);
```

However, some people say that's a security flaw. I dug a little deeper and I believe the best method I found out, seems to be this:

```
kses_remove_filters();
$id = wp_insert_post($postData);
kses_init_filters();
```

Without setting

```
'filter' => true,
```

I hope this helps everyone! :)